# how can i export data out of oracle to salesforce LOV automatically everyday?

Tags: oracle, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I would like to export the data from oracle to salesforce . Is there a way to do this?

can't find a way to connect directly.

Thank you.

Comment: sqlcl unload can write table data to disk (csv/json). You can load it from there. Another approach is kafkaconnect. JDBC source connector and Salesforce sink connector.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce exposes only REST & SOAP API access, there's no ODBC/JDBC/... direct connector to underlying database.

In SQL Server world there's a package that pretends SF is a remote server or whatever is the term (https://www.cdata.com/dbamp/), bunch of stored procedures etc that hide the API access. For Oracle world... look into https://sesamesoftware.com/salesforce/ ? (I'm not affiliated with any of these)

ETL and ESB tools (Informatica, Azure Data Factory, Talend, MuleSoft) have SF connectors too and there's paid extra [OData-compatible API](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_about.htm&type=5) if that's something you'd prefer.

If you want to roll something out yourself - Salesforce Data Loader and SFDX (tools your SF Admin / Developer probably already use) can import/export CSV files, can be scripted from commandline.

Or write a program in Java / .Net / PHP / Python. Either craft the REST / SOAP messages (there are WSDLs to speed you up) or there are ready libraries & examples.

Whatever you're comfortable with really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party ODBC and JDBC connectors, such as the ones we offer at DataDirect. https://www.progress.com/connectors/salesforce

We also offer a data gateway which can provide access to Salesforce as a relational source, while also providing a way to OData-enable existing sources (think MSSQL, Oracle, Rest, etc) for use with Salesforce Connect - their external data feature to access data where it lives.

https://www.progress.com/connectors/cloud-data-integration

Full disclosure - I am an SE with DataDirect.